# kotlin suppress warning deprecated for Android

Tags: android, warnings, kotlin

In my Kotlin Android project, I am using a function that has been deprecated starting from api 23, which is quite recent. So I need a way to disable those deprecated warnings. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Please give a thumbs up on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8087, if you're interested in suppressing all deprecations.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use [`@Suppress`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-suppress/) annotation with argument `"DEPRECATION"`:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
someObject.theDeprecatedFunction()
```

Instead of a single statement, you can also mark a function, a class or a file (`@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION")` in its beginning) with the annotation to suppress all the deprecation warnings issued there.

In IntelliJ IDEA this can also be done through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu with caret placed on code with deprecation warning.

Comment: Fyi, if it were an overridden function, using Alt+Enter would give you @Suppress("OverridingDeprecatedMember")

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the warning for just one method? I am using a deprecated class in only one method, but kotlin still complains about the import unless I suppress the whole file.

Answer (score 25):

In **Kotlin**

> @SuppressWarnings

is changed to

> @Suppress

For removing the strike through deprecation warnings you should add,

```
 @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
```

to remove the warning from the super method.
By adding

```
@Suppress("OverridingDeprecatedMember")
```

The warning of the function will get removed.
So, the complete annotation will be;

```
@Suppress("OverridingDeprecatedMember", "DEPRECATION")
```

As an additional note the deprecation should be written as "DEPRECATION" ( *use capital letters*)

Comment: "note the deprecation should be written as "DEPRECATION" ( use capital letters)". I don't think this is true.