# Kotlin 'rem' as replacement for 'mod' not available?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

For `count % 2` I get the warning

> Warning:(137, 17) Kotlin: 'mod(Int): Int' is deprecated. Use rem(other) instead

and the Intellij IDE provides for an automated correction to `count.rem(2)` which I then get flagged as an error due to an unresolved reference to `rem`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16372) in the Kotlin IDE plugin.

It arises from the deprecation of the `mod` function in Kotlin 1.1, which should be replaced by `rem` (see *Other changes* in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/12/kotlin-1-1-m04-is-here/)). But the IDE plugin incorrectly reports and suggest the quick fix even for earlier Kotlin versions which didn't have `rem`.

Unitl it is fixed, you can either update your project to Kotlin 1.1 or [suppress the warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676512/kotlin-supress-warning-deprecated-for-android), or just ignore them.