# Is there a way to ignore certain warnings in the kotlin compiler?

Tags: kotlin, deprecated, deprecation-warning

A project that I work on has no-warnings set in the compileOptions. Is there a way to stop Deprecated usages from being flagged as a warning?

I like to use `@Deprecated` annotations to prevent making too many changes in one merge request, but this prevents me from doing so.

The best scenario is to have Kotlin ignore any `@Deprecated` annotations within only our application code. Second best thing would be to remove this as a warning entirely.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin suppress warning deprecated for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676512/kotlin-suppress-warning-deprecated-for-android)

Comment: That only shows you how to make a file or class as deprecated. My question is about an entire project. I definitely don't want to add thousands of Suppression annotations to every class. My question is specific to the compiler configuration.

Comment: You're right. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488930/how-to-suppress-specific-kotlinc-javac-compiler-warnings) is somewhat similar but doesn't have any answers, unfortunately

Comment: Ah, but that did point me to the overall answer in the comments, thank you!

Comment: Please give a thumbs up on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8087, if you're interested in this feature.